# Write WHERE GraphQL queries with Apollo gql

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Running this query on my Playground works perfectly:

```
 query {
    users(where:{email_contains: "b"}) {
      nodes {
        email
        firstName
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
```

But I am unable to convert it into this format to use in my code with Apollo gql. How can I fix it in a way that I can pass any variable I want? Along with the `where`

```
interface Input {
  email: String;
  firstName: String;
  lastName: String;
}

export const LoadUsersQuery = gql`
  query users(where $email: String!){
    users {
      nodes {
        firstName
        email
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
`;
```

From the schema, I know that:

```
users(
where: UserFilter
): UserConnection
```

```
type UserFilter{
  email_contains: string
  firstName_contains: string
}
```

etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to define something like

```
 query {
    usersList($email_contains: string) {
      users(email_contains: $email_contains}) {
        nodes {
          email
          firstName
        }
        totalCount
      }
   }
}
```

Check out the docs for more info: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/queries/.